# Filereader throwing "FileNotFoundException". How do I read and write to a file?

Tags: java, android, file, file-io, filenotfoundexception

My code throws `"FileNotFoundException"` error. What is the proper way of reading and writing to a file? Is this error just thrown because the file is not created yet, or is it because of a misunderstanding of filereading and filewriting??? Thanks
My code:

```
 public class EditPeople_ListFragment extends ListFragment {

    public Pair<List<String>, List<String>> ReadPeopleFile(FileReader peopleReader){
        ///Soon parsed into a string list, by delimiting and separating into two string arrays,
        char characterList[] = new char[10000]; // I'm assuming that 1000 is enough here
        int numChars = 0;
        try {
            numChars = peopleReader.read(characterList);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        String parseString = new String(characterList, 0, numChars);///Creates a string parseString.
        List<String> parseString_array = new ArrayList<String>();///Initialises a list of strings
        parseString_array = Arrays.asList(parseString.split(";"));///Splits the parseString into the parseString_array
        List <String> mobileNumber = new ArrayList<String>();///Initialises a list of strings, meant to be mobile numbers.
        List <String> name = new ArrayList<String>();///Initialises a list of string, meant to be names
        String[] parts = new String[2];
        for (String peopleDetails : parseString_array){///sets up a loop for each of the strings in parseString_array, to be split into mobile numbers, and name. 
            ///delimiter: ";" is for each peopleDetail string. Delimiter: "," separates mobile number and names in each peopleDetails string.
            parts = peopleDetails.split(",");
            mobileNumber.add(parts[0]);
            name.add(parts[1]);         


        }
        try {
            peopleReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return new Pair(mobileNumber, name);
        ///Then use on return value nameList = ------.getname();
        ///and use --------.getmobileNumber();








    }



    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FileReader peopleFile_Reader = new FileReader(new File(getFilesDir(), "PartyApp_PeopleFile"))
        Pair<List<String>, List<String>> returnedpair = ReadPeopleFile(peopleFile_Reader);    
        List<String> mobileList = returnedpair.first;
        List<String> nameList = returnedpair.second;
        List<String> people_List = null;
        if(nameList.size() == mobileList.size()){///Checks the list are the same length; should be, but need to add a check to AddPeople, to check both fields are filled and correct
            for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); ++i) {///
                people_List.add(i, nameList.get(i) + "," + mobileList.get(i));


            }
        }



        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(), R.id.ListView_EditPeopleFragment, people_List);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file exists and is accessbile? What value is returned by ` getFilesDir()`?

Comment: the file should be on internal memory, and in the equivalent of "program files" on android. I think the getFilesDir() "Returns a File representing an internal directory for your app."

Comment: IMO thats right. In the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir()) I found for `getFilesDir()`: __returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with openFileOutput(String, int) are stored.__ Did you create the file `PartyApp_PeopleFile` this way?

Comment: Yes, in a different activity, although getFilesDir() is now returning a "The method getFilesDir() is undefined for the type EditPeople_ListFragment" error message, based off code from an example.